# Installing on NTFS partition

Tags: installation, partitioning, backup, ntfs, testdisk

Hello I currently have win xp installed on my pc , I got two drives C: (main one) and D: which I use as a backup drive and save all my videos & docs in.

Last time I installed Ubuntu , it gave me an option to replace windows XP , I thought it will install on C: so I clicked yes , and it wiped all the data on whole drive.

So I want to install Ubuntu only on my C: as I cant backup my D: cuz it got over 100 GB of important data so external backup not possible...

Last time I recovered that data using testdisk (recovering 130 GB took lot of time..)
So this possible or testdisk last resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy. When you go to install, ***BOOT INTO THE LIVE DESKTOP***.

Next, go into GParted (Alt+F2 gparted).

Select your C drive, and DELETE. Click apply. It will take a while.

Now, create a new partition in the "empty space". Make sure it's EXT4.

Next, apply those changes. When done, close GParted.

Now, start the Ubuntu installer. When it asks you where to install Ubuntu, go into "Advanced Mode" and select the EXT4 space. Tell it to mount that as /. Select your D drive and tell it to mount as something like /backup (or whatever you want). Make sure the format checkbox is NOT checked. Then, proceed with install.

If all goes right, congrats! If not, recover that partition and fast!

Typically, you ALWAYS want to have backups on an external disc. Just safer (and less chance of accidental wipe).